# Search by node ID

Tags: nodes, search

I am using the Search module and I would love to add a function to it which gives a user the possibility to enter a node ID in the search field and look for it. Is there any chance to take this effect?

Comment: You can also do it using views instead of using search modules..

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: You don't add functions to existing modules, including the ones that come with Drupal.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since you are asking for code, you should show the code you have. We don't aim to be a "write my code" site, but we could help if you have problems with your code. We also cannot explain basic concepts like "how to create a module." As side note, if I want to look for the node with ID equal to 51, on Drupal.org, I simply go to https://drupal.org/node/51; I don't need Drupal.org implements such functionality.

Comment: I never asked you for a code. I didn't ask you about basic concept like "how to create a module". I just wanted you to explain generally how to make it work with views. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Actually, you didn't say you were interested in doing something with the Views module, in your question, so the only alternative would be with code. Plus, your question doesn't show any effort in finding the solution; it would be like going in a cooking site saying "I want to make a cake; is there any chance to do this?"

Comment: Great comparison to cakes mate. I just wanted to get some tips. Not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a view with page display
- Add Filter Node : ID
- Expose Above Filter to user

Please find the view exported below which you can import using views import functionality..

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'search_by_node_id';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Search By Node ID';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Search By Node ID';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'nid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['expose']['label'] = 'Node ID';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['expose']['operator'] = 'nid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'search-by-node-id';
$translatables['search_by_node_id'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Search By Node ID'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Node ID'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

- Navigate to 'search-by-node-id' to see results once you import view..

[image]

Comment: In the case you show, would the view return also a node with ID equal to 510? If it is going to show only the node exactly matching the ID, then it is useless; there is a easier way to look for a node.

Comment: Thanks great Anil. Can it be integrated with normal search?